# When should we use `accessibilityRole` in React Native?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

Is this correct? I'm afraid it will read the word 'switch' twice to the user.

```
<Switch
      accessible={true}
      accessibilityLabel="Switch button"
      accessibilityHint="Double tap to toggle setting"
      accessibilityRole="switch"   
/>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple notes on accessibility here:

- As of 0.60, all interactive React Native components are accessible by default. (`accessible=true`)
- Beware when using the `accessible` parameter. It will bundle any child elements into one accessible component and a screen reader will not allow users to select individual components when true. (You may need to override the default behavior because of this.)
- Particularly with labels, remember to use full punctuation, or you may create unintended and overwhelming run-on sentences.
- For UX, your label should read the purpose of the switch in a concise manner. Reading it without context, I have no idea what this toggle would actually *do*.

To answer your question:

You are correct that this setup would read out "switch button" twice, followed by the hint.

I tested the `<Switch>` component on an iPad just now with VoiceOver. By default, it is accessible and reads with a role of "button". Giving it a parameter of `accessibilityRole='switch'` reads with a role of "switch button" and automatically includes the "Double tap to toggle setting." hint.

The following component will read to the user as, "Airplane mode. *switch button* ... Double tap to toggle setting."

```
<Switch
      accessibilityLabel="Airplane mode."
      accessibilityRole="switch"   
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`accessibilityRole` communicates the purpose of a component to the user of assistive technology.

For more information please find the below in official documentation

https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibilityrole-android-ios